# How to solve timeout error in c?

Tags: c, algorithm

I was running this code to remove the duplicates of a string.

```
   #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>

    int main()
    {
        char str[100];
        int i, j, k;

        printf("\n Please Enter any String :  ");
        scanf("%s",str);

        for(i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
        {
            for(j = i + 1; str[j] != '\0'; j++)
            {
                if(str[j] == str[i])  
                {
                    for(k = j; str[k] != '\0'; k++)
                    {
                        str[k] = str[k + 1];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        printf("\n %s ", str);

        return 0;
    }
```

When i run this program the compiler shows a Time-out error. Can anyone help me out solve this error!

Comment: no timeout for me

Comment: Are you sure it's the **compiler** that show a "time out" error ?

Comment: I doubt the *compiler* show a timeout. Rather I believe that it's an online judge/competition site that times out.

Comment: Which compiler?

Comment: With a `O(n³)` algorithm, if you're submitting to an online judge system, it's very much possible you can get a timeout.

Comment: The error is that you have used an algorithm that is too slow. There are better ways to remove duplicates from a string. Since this is a challenge problem, giving you the solution is inappropriate. The goal is for you to think about alternate ways of solving the problem.

Comment: Incidentally, are you sure the strings supplied in input are limited to 100 characters?

Comment: Aside: are you sure the judge will like you printing a prompt, and printing leading newlines and extra spaces? The output must be *exactly* how the problem describes it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply guys!@EricPostpischil ill try another way to solve this challenge thank you

Comment: @AishwaryaGanesh Well, you could copy only the non duplicate letter, not shifting the entire string each time. When you for loop the string, you have a char (str[i]). If this char is not between str[0] and str[i - 1], you copy it, if it is, you don't copy it. If you copy it in the same string like you do, you have to keep another iterator (k, for example) and incremetn it each time you copy a new char.

Answer (score 0):

There are fast memory-efficient algorithms for solving the problem.

Here is one, described in text/pseudocode. Memory requirement is constant and only depends on the number of bits in `char`. Time Complexity is O(n).

```
Create and initialize an array of flags that keep track of characters encountered.

Loop:
  Read the next character. End loop if there was no more input.

  If the character is flagged in the array then 
    continue.
  Else 
    Flag the character in the array.
    Print the character.
End loop
```

Hint:
On some systems `char` is signed. Be sure to use `unsigned` values to index the array.